# Query to find documents that have extra elements in array

Tags: mongodb

I have this documents :

```
db.article.insert({attributes: [{value: 'a'}]})
db.article.insert({attributes: [{value: 'a'}, {value: 'c'}]})
```

I need a **query** (not an aggregate, because it will be used in an updateMany) that returns the documents having extra attributes.value elements than an array.

```
db.article.find({"attributes.value": <extra elements than>: ["a"] })
// should return the document that has at least one other value than "a"
{attributes: [{value: 'a'}, {value: 'c'}]}
```

So far I tried :

```
db.article.find({'attributes.value': { $nin: ['a'] }})
```

That returns nothing (all documents have 'a' has value)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking or why you don't want to use aggregate

Comment: I updated the OP. No aggregate because it needs to be used in an update (but $expr is OK)

Comment: Your example showing array with extra element, not extra fields.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn right, I corrected the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.article.find({attributes: { $elemMatch: { value: {$ne: 'a'}}}})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use several conditions combined with `$or` checking `$size` of the array:

```
db.article.find({$or: [
  {"attributes.value": "a", "attributes": {$not: {$size: 1}}},
  {"attributes.value": {$nin: ["a"]}, "attributes": {$not: {$size: 0}}},
]})
```

The first one matches documents with `attributes` that has `{value: "a"}` element + at least 1 more.

The second condition matches documents with non-empty `attributes` that has no `{value: "a"}` element.

It will match documents with **any** extra element in the array, even if it doesn't have `value`, e.g.

```
db.article.insert({attributes: [{notvalue: 'a'}]})
```

will still be a match.

If you need to match documents where `attributes` has at least 1 extra element with non-empty `value`, there is no other option but use `$expr` with aggregation expressions:

```
db.article.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ 
    { $size: { $filter: { 
        input: "$attributes", 
        as: "attribute", 
        cond: { $ne: [ { $ifNull: [ "$$attribute.value", "a" ] }, "a" ]  } 
    } } },
    0
] } })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

First one is [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query and second is [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection

```
db.collection.find({
  "attributes": { "$elemMatch": { "value": { "$ne": "a" } } }
}, {
  "attributes": { "$elemMatch": { "value": { "$ne": "a" } } }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$nin` to filter out arrays contains other elements than predefined elements:

```
db.article.find({"attributes.value": {$nin: ["a"] }})
```

Comment: it does not give me the extra element behaviour :/